# Reverse Delay in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my very first time coding with jquery from scratch, which is an immense improvement from a few weeks ago. If the answer is completely obvious, I apologize; I did search pretty thoroughly, but either I couldn't find what I needed or I just didn't word it right.

In this description bar, what I'd like to happen is for the small text to slide up, then for the big text to slide down, which I've sort of forced by adding a delay. When you click the button again, I'd like for the opposite reaction to happen--for the big text to slide up, and then the small text slide down. However, what's happening is that the small text appears again before the big text disappears--which makes sense, considering the delay I've added, but it's not what I'd like to happen.

Is there anything I could change for the opposite reaction to happen every time the description is toggled, or am I sort of stuck with the forced option?

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".followme").click(function(){
    $(".astrology").delay(1000).slideToggle(1000);
    $(".desc").slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == '- less' ? "+ more" : "- less");
     });
});
```

And the ever helpful [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n1puthvo/1/).

Thank you for taking the time to read, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use an `if` statement?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".followme").click(function(){
    if ($(".astrology").is(':visible'))
    {
      $(".astrology").delay(1000).slideToggle(1000);
      $(".desc").slideToggle(1000);
      $(this).text("+ more");
    } else {
      $(".astrology").delay(1000).slideToggle(1000);
      $(".desc").slideToggle(1000);
      $(this).text("- less");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
  .zodiac {
        width:100px;
        border-radius:6px;
        color:#101010;
        font-family:calibri;
        font-size:10px;
        font-weight:100;
        position:absolute;
        line-height:7px;
        top:135px;
        left:110px;
        border-bottom:3px double white;
        padding:3px;
        text-align:justify;
        margin:auto auto;
    }
    
    .signs {
        
        width:100px;
        color:#101010;
        padding:3px;
        font-family:calibri;
        font-size:10px;
        font-weight:100;
        position:relative;
        top:25px;
        left:0px;
        margin-top:-12px;
        text-align:center;
        text-shadow:0 0 3px #a9dcf1, 0 0 5px #a9dcf1;
        display:block;
    }
    
    .signs a{
        color:#101010;
        text-decoration:none;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    
    .signs a:hover {
        color:#101010;
        text-shadow:0 0 3px #a9dcf1, 0 0 20px #a9dcf1, 0 0 25px #a9dcf1, 0 0 20px #a9dcf1;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .followme {
        color:#101010;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        text-shadow:0 0 3px #fff;
        padding:3px;
    }
    
    .astrology {width:100px;
        color:#101010;
        font-family:calibri;
        font-size:9px;
        font-weight:100;
        position:relative;
        line-height:10px;
        padding:3px;
        text-align:justify;
        margin:auto auto;
        display:none;
        
    }
    
    .um {
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zodiac">
            TITLE<br/>
            <div class="desc">
            <small><small><small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pretium ut erat quis lacinia. Mauris tristique purus sit amet eros porta fermentum.</small></small></small></div>
             <div class="followme">+ more</div>
            <div class="astrology">Nunc sagittis posuere velit. Duis gravida, dolor non luctus convallis, nunc orci laoreet orci, nec porta risus ante quis libero. Maecenas fermentum porttitor nibh, quis aliquet odio imperdiet eu. Vivamus tempor, felis vel cursus bibendum, ligula nulla dignissim velit, et rhoncus sapien nunc et velit. Duis eget lacus porta, sollicitudin elit vitae, aliquam dui.</div>
            <div class="signs"><a>refresh</a> | <a>ask</a> | <a>archive</a></div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. Clearly, I still have a lot to learn. Just had to switch one of the delays to get the desired effect. Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @SugarChiffon No problem. Happy programming :).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: attach separate handlers to the more and less options. http://jsfiddle.net/c499rc7h/

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#more").click(function(){
    $(".desc").slideUp(1000, function(){
        $(".astrology").slideDown(1000);
        $(".followme").toggle();
    });
});

$("#less").click(function(){
    $(".astrology").slideUp(1000, function(){
        $(".desc").slideDown(1000);
        $(".followme").toggle();
    });
});
```

});

Comment: I would recommend using the callback options of slideUp/Down/Toggle, rather than using a delay. Basically you chain the functions together rather than relying on timings. The reason this may be preferable is that you reduce duplication.